# Get the current logged in user from a Windows 8 store application

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Is there anyway the get the current logged in user name from a windows store application?

I've looked at the Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation class but this only returns the current users first name, last name and display name.

But I want the username that the user used to log into the domain.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have set the Enterprise Authentication in my application manifest capabilities and than use this code to get the domain username:

```
var username = await Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation.GetDomainNameAsync();
```